# jwplayer in modal - fullscreen button closes modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jwplayer

I have a problem with jwplayer embed in a modal (Bootstrap). 
When I open the modal the player loads fine and I can click play to start the video. But when I click on the fullscreen button of jqplayer, the video changes to fullscreen and after about one second the fullscreen and modal closes and the whole page reloads...

Do you have an idea why this happens?

Here is the code of jwplayer:

```
<div id="jwplayer-video">
<div class="progress progress-striped active" style="width: 80px;">
     <div class="bar" style="width: 80%;"></div>
</div>
<b>&nbsp; &nbsp; Video wird geladen ...</b>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("jwplayer-video").setup({
    playlist: [{
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg", 
        sources: [{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.flv",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.webm",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.mp4",
        },{
            file: "{$bilderpfad}/u{$ubungsid}.ogv",
        }]
    }]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this?